# Ruby Watir to get specific html element of a page

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have already try this one:

```
puts browser.text
```

and it works. I would like to ask if it is possible to display or print only the specific element or html tags.
For example this one:

```
<button class="btn btn-add" data-role="add">Add New User</button>
```

Is there any way to get this element only? Not the whole Page source.
 I also try

```
puts @browser.button(:class => "btn btn-add").html
```

and the error is:

```
1) Error:
test_login(TC_Login):
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: invalid 'in' operand a
    [remote server] http://sample.org/user/ line 68 > Function:18:in `G'
    [remote server] http://sample.org/user/ line 68 > Function:18:in `anonymous/</<'
    [remote server] http://sample.org/user/ line 68 > Function:15:in `anonymous/<'
    [remote server] http://sample.org/user/ line 68 > Function:15:in `anonymous'
    [remote server] http://sample.org/user/:68:in `handleEvaluateEvent'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:640:in `raw_execute'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:618:in `execute'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:339:in `executeScript'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:193:in `execute_script'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/atoms.rb:20:in `execute_atom'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:290:in `outer_html'
    excel.rb:277:in `test_login'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why Andrew Leaf answer doesn't work for you, it's simple and correct way that should work, could you post an error that it throws?
But you can also try this:

```
browser.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("btn-add")[0];').html
```

Comment: What browser/version do you use?

Comment: I am using firefox 35.0.1

Comment: Then I would recommend you to: 1. Try to update your gems; 2. Downgrade your Firefox to version 34, because there are some problems in Firefox 35.x, that were detected in selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Is it possible to downgrade only the browser you are going to use. Not the default one?

Comment: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2249039 - read this article, it would help you to install two version of firefox. Then change your PATH variable such that it will include path to firefox 34.x and will not include path to firefox 35.x. Now your webdriver should use version 34.x, test your code. Change your PATH variable to initial condition. P.S. don't forget to restart console after each PATH variable change, if you use console to test your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
@browser.button(:class => "btn btn-add").html
```

That should display the HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.button(:class => "btn btn-add")
```

Comment: Hi. Ahm.. Thank you for the response..I would like to add a question. Isn't possible to display the html element???? I try puts @browser.button(:class => "btn btn-add").text.. but it was not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

underlying HTML code for an element on the page can be displayed using method inner_html

puts browser.button(:class => "btn btn-add").inner_html